# Getting consul: kv.get: request timed out (33000ms)

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, consul

I have deployed statefulset cluster of consul having 3 nodes. Consul version is 1.11.2 its was working fine from last few months but now i am getting consul: kv.get: request timed out (33000ms) at the time of microservices connection to consul

error.grouping_name : consul: kv.get: request timed out (33000ms)
In last one month there are 12 occurrences of the error.

Its not happening continuously which means after one error occurrence it tries to retry and the get request is successful.

please help me to resolve the error in KV get consul as it is hampering my Production.

[consul: kv.get: request timed out (33000ms][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqzhv.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have updated the question please check.

Comment: Could you provide the consul server log and consul client agent in the near same timestamp? Seem like its consul no cluster leader issue